# Repeat if until true [python]

Tags: python, selenium

I want `if` to search for a CSS selector and if this is found, the script is carried out further, and if the CSS selector is not found, it should repeat the `if function` until it's true.

Here is my code:

```
if driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#buyTools > div.prl6-sm.prl0-lg > fieldset > div > div:nth-child(7) > label'):
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="buyTools"]/div[1]/fieldset/div/div[7]/label').click()
else:
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: So you want to repeat it ``while not`` true?

Comment: Yes exactly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a while loop with some arbitrary wait to accomplish this like:

```
from time import sleep

while not driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#buyTools > div.prl6-sm.prl0-lg > fieldset > div > div:nth-child(7) > label'):
    sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="buyTools"]/div[1]/fieldset/div/div[7]/label').click()
```

Comment: You might not want to add `time.sleep`, since `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector` takes some time to run as well

Comment: You could adjust the sleep to fit your needs or remove it altogether and just use `pass` if that's true

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


WebDriverWait(driver,5000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#buyTools > div.prl6-sm.prl0-lg > fieldset > div > div:nth-child(7) > label")))
```

use in build webdriverwait for this wait to re invent the wheel using different code